# the relation of Local Truncation error and approximation error

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm students at undergraduate school  2year

I don't have much background  knowledge

I study nummerical analysis Runge - Kutta Method not a few

my text book induce Runge - Kutta midpoint method by 2 order Taylor series $T^2$ and it's approximating function $a_1f(t+\alpha_1,y+\beta_1)$

this approximation error is $O(h^2)$

since $w_{i+1}=w_i + h T^2(t_i,w_i) $ where $T^2(t,y)$ is order 2 Taylor for f(t,y). its local truncation error is also two

then replace $ T^2(t_i,w_i)$ to $ f(t_i+\frac{h}{2},w_i+\frac{h}{2}f(t_i,w_i))$
thus $w_{i+1}=w_i + hf(t_i+\frac{h}{2},w_i+\frac{h}{2}f(t_i,w_i))$

is this local truncation error also two because approximation error and local truncation error of $w_{i+1}=w_i + h T^2(t_i,w_i) $ is same for two?

is it correct?

sorry to my poor English ability

Comment: Local truncation error is a technical term: it means the error made by taking a Taylor approximation over one time step.

Comment: (Cont.) "Approximation error" is not a completely technical term. My guess is that it means "global error". In general global error is one order worse than local truncation error. That's because the global error is basically the sum of all the local truncation errors, but there are $O(1/h)$ of those on a finite time interval. In the full story there is a bit more to it, which is where stability of the discrete method comes into play; basically the above is the story if the discrete method is stable.

Comment: then why $w_{i+1}=w_i+hf(t_i+\frac{h}{2},w_i+\frac{h}{2}f(t_i,w_i))$ is local truncation error two?

Comment: If I recall correctly, that method is "second order accurate", which means that the global error (assuming stability) is $O(h^2)$ and the local error (of approximating the overall expression $hf(t,y)$) is $O(h^3)$. I should emphasize this point: the exponent depends on how you group terms together. For example, a $O(h^2)$ error in approximating $f(t,y)$ produces a $O(h^3)$ error in approximating $hf(t,y)$ for example.

Comment: my text book say that this truncation error of  mid point method is $ O(h^2) $

Comment: That can make sense, but you need to pay careful attention to how exactly they define "local truncation error". If it is the error in approximating $y(t_{n+1})$ given exact knowledge of $y(t_n)$, then it should be $O(h^3)$. But if it is the error in approximating $f(t_n,y(t_n))$, then it should be $O(h^2)$.